# How can I export a package of a prefab using editorwindow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ExportObjects : EditorWindow
{
    //Creates a new menu (Examples) with a menu item (Create Prefab)
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Create Prefab", false, -1)]
    static void CreatePrefab()
    {
        //Keep track of the currently selected GameObject(s)
        GameObject[] objectArray = Selection.gameObjects;

        //Loop through every GameObject in the array above
        foreach (GameObject gameObject in objectArray)
        {
            //Set the path as within the Assets folder, and name it as the GameObject's name with the .prefab format
            string localPath = "Assets/Prefabs to export/" + gameObject.name + ".prefab";

            //Check if the Prefab and/or name already exists at the path
            if (AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(localPath, typeof(GameObject)))
            {
                //Create dialog to ask if User is sure they want to overwrite existing Prefab
                if (EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Are you sure?",
                    "The Prefab already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?",
                    "Yes",
                    "No"))
                //If the user presses the yes button, create the Prefab
                {
                    CreateNew(gameObject, localPath);
                    Export(gameObject, localPath);
                }
            }
            //If the name doesn't exist, create the new Prefab
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " is not a Prefab, will convert");
                CreateNew(gameObject, localPath);
                Export(gameObject, localPath);
            }
        }
    }

    // Disable the menu item if no selection is in place
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Create Prefab", true, -1)]
    static bool ValidateCreatePrefab()
    {
        return Selection.activeGameObject != null;
    }

    static void CreateNew(GameObject obj, string localPath)
    {
        //Create a new Prefab at the path given
        Object prefab = PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(obj, localPath);
        PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(obj, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
    }

    static void Export(GameObject obj, string localPath)
    {
        AssetDatabase.ExportPackage(localPath, obj.name);
    }
}
```

The first problem is in the Export method. It's getting there and doing the line:

```
AssetDatabase.ExportPackage(localPath, obj.name);
```

But it's not creating any package file on the hard disk in the localPath.

Second problem is that I'm not sure if doing false, -1 is right (But it's working).

Third how to change the line:

```
PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(obj, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
```

ReplacePrefab is obsolete and should be replaced like in the line before by: SaveAsPrefabAsset and I tried but in this lines the parameters are not the same as above: obj, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab So I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the package is not getting created because you don't have directory "Prefabs to export". 
One suggested way is to create directory would be

```
string defaultPath = Application.dataPath + "/Prefabs to export/";
if (!Directory.Exists(defaultPath))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(defaultPath);
}
```

This will create the driectory if it doesn't exist for you. It will reach AssetDatabase.ExportPackage but editor must have thrown some errors. Do check on editor log.

Moving on to second part of the question -1 which you have set in MenuItem is for the order at which your button will be displayed in the menu. You can set to 0 or 1 or even 10 as per your requirements. I believe the topmost buttons in menu are kept at 0 so setting it to -1 will make your button coming up above the other buttons in Unity.

As of now I'm unaware of any replacement method and after digging through a bit I found that it was marked by obsolete without replacement as per the [Unity's team](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-generate-prefabs-w-scripts-w-the-new-system.613747/#post-4113010). So you can use this Replace prefab in meanwhile till the issue gets sorted out.

> We’re working on a replacement for ReplacePrefab. You can keep using the obsolete API in the mean time. The replacement was meant to have been done when we shipped but didn't make it. It's a mistake on our part that the old method was marked obsolete without the replacement being ready. Sorry for the inconvenience.